# iPhone iOs 5, dynamically change the height of the scrollviewer based on content height not working?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiscrollview

What i am doing is to get data from the database. I then want to add that data into text views and add those textviews onto a scrollviewer.

But nothing is showing up. I know that there is data but it's just not showing. Most likely i'm missing to set something.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSUInteger height = 0;

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [data count]; i++){
        DBMiscData *row = (DBMiscData *) [data objectAtIndex:i];

        if (row.text != nil){
            UITextView *tv = [[UITextView alloc] init];
            [tv setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
            tv.text = row.text;
            [_scrollerView addSubview:tv];
            [tv sizeToFit];
            height+=(NSUInteger)tv.frame.size.height;
        }
    }

    [_scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [_scrollerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, height)];
    [_scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, height)];
    [_scroller addSubview:_scrollerView];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

**Updated code and what i am after**

What i want is simple same as i have in android.

android:layout_width="fill_parent" and android:layout_height="wrap_content".

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? As it looks like from provided code you should use the UITableView instead.

Comment: Its not just text in the end. Will also be pictures and lines (like <hr>)

Comment: You should use a TableView with custom Cells. Take a look at: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CGRectFromString(aString)` does not return you the rectangle in which that text fits.
If you have a string like `{{5, 10}, {100, 130}}` , that method will create a CGRect for you that will have origin = `CGPointMake(5,10)` and size = `CGSizeMake(100,130)`.
If you have a string like 'bananas' . The CGRect resulting from this will always be `CGRectZero` ( aka CGRectMake(0,0,0,0) ).

That's why your height is zero.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Yes and no. Explains why it returns 0. But what should i then use to create a correct textview. What i want is the same as in android programming: android:layout_width="fill_parent" and android:layout_height="wrap_content".

Comment: I don't know android programming , but in order to dynamically get the size of your text view you have to do this: 1) set it's height to a large value 2) Set it's text 3) call `[myTextView sizeToFit];` 4) Now you have your height calculated dynamically. You can get it with textView.frame.size.height. Careful: I wasn't aware of the first step since I didn't read anywhere in the documentation about it. But it proved itself right a few times.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound silly but how about using

```
height+=(NSUInteger)tv.frame.size.height;
```

instead of

```
height+=(NSUInteger)tv.bounds.size.height;
```

Comment: Tried this but frame.size.height is also 0